# Centering a pgf-pie chart with legend with respect to center of the chart, not the entire figure

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgf-pie

I have a pie chart with a legend at the side made using pgf-pie. It is centered with respect to the center point of the entire figure, including the legend.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz, 12pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames, rgb]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgf-pie}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, positioning, shadows}
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pie[sum=auto,text=legend]{10/A,20/B,30/C,10/D, 56.8/E}
\end{tikzpicture}
 \caption{Caption}
 \vspace*{1em}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Screenshot with an indicated line crossing the center of my chart, perpendicular to the caption, showing that it is not properly centered.

[image]

Is there a way to center it with respect to the center of my pie chart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, I save a legend-less pie chart in box 0 and the desired one in box 2. Then, I typeset it as such

```
\makebox[\wd0][l]{\box2}
```

Here is the MWE.

```
\documentclass[tikz, 12pt, a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames, rgb]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgf-pie}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, positioning, shadows}
\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\sbox0{\tikz{\pie[sum=auto]{100/}}}%
\sbox2{\tikz{\pie[sum=auto,text=legend]{10/A,20/B,30/C,10/D, 56.8/E}}}%
\makebox[\wd0][l]{\box2}
 \caption{Caption}
 \vspace*{1em}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]